# How do query with a OR and AND operator in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to make query in Codeigniter via Active Records:

```
if (isset($data['where']['and'])) {
     $this->db->where($data['where']['and']);
}

if (isset($data['where']['or'])) {
     $this->db->or_where_in('idSpec', $data['where']['or']);
}
```

I want to get:

```
WHERE name = 1 AND (idSpec = 2 OR idSpec = 3 OR idSpec = 4);
```

But now I get:

```
WHERE name = 1 OR idSpec = 2 OR idSpec = 3 OR idSpec = 4;
```

Comment: are you sure your query producing `WHERE name = 1` ? what does `$data['where']['and']`; and `$data['where']['or']` contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code.

```
if (isset($data['where']['and'])) {
      $this->db->where($data['where']['and']);
    }
    if (isset($data['where']['or'])) {
      $this->db->where("(idSpec = 2 OR idSpec = 3 OR idSpec = 4;)", NULL, FALSE);
    }
```

Comment: Instead `idSpec = 2 OR idSpec = 3 OR idSpec = 4;` can I specify array?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your `$data['where']['or']` contains some ids.
This may help you.

```
if (isset($data['where']['or'])) 
{
    $or_conditions='(idSpec ='.implode(' OR idSpec = ',$data['where']['or']).')';
    $this->db->where($or_conditions);//if this produce error use bellow one
    //$this->db->where($or_conditions,'',false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic method to select data from database I'm using well for a long time..

```
/**
 * Le wild function to make a life better.
 * Doing abrakadabra
 *
 * @param        $table
 * @param bool   $selector
 * @param string $order
 * @param bool   $start
 * @param bool   $limit
 * @param        $return
 *
 * @return mixed
 */

public function _getCustomTableData($table, $selector = FALSE, $order = 'id DESC', $start = FALSE, $limit = FALSE, $return = FALSE, $group_by = FALSE)
{
    $query = $return ? $this->db->select($return) : $this->db->select('*');

    if ( $selector ) {
        if ( isset($selector['mixed_selection']) && $selector['mixed_selection'] == TRUE ) {
            $query = $this->db->where($selector['mixed_selection']);
        } else {
            foreach ( $selector as $select_array ):
                $query = $this->db->where($select_array);
            endforeach;
        }
    }

    if ( $group_by ) {
        $query = $this->db->group_by($group_by);
    }

    $query = $this->db->order_by($order);
    if ( $start && $limit ) {
        $query = $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    }
    if ( ! $start && $limit ) {
        $query = $this->db->limit($limit);
    }

    // proceed
    $query = $this->db->get($table);

    if ( $limit == TRUE && $limit == 1 ) {
        $query = $query->row_array();
        if ( $return ) {
            return $query[$return];
        } else {
            return $query;
        }
    } else {
        $query = $query->result_array();
        return $query;
    }

}
```

and query looks like:

```
$this->_getCustomTableData('table', array(array('selector' => '1', 'time >=' => time())), 'id DESC', FALSE, 1, 'id');
```

it's like:

```
SELECT 'id' FROM `table` WHERE `selector` = 1 AND `time` >= 1472582... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

or you can use "mixed selection"

```
$this->_getCustomTableData('table', array('mixed_selection' => 'selector = 1 AND time >= 1472582...'), 'id DESC', FALSE, 1, 'id');
```

and the result will be the same. I have wrote this method when I was beginner with CI and it helped me a lot :)